# Convert NIB to XIB without Interface Builder

Tags: xcode4, nib

I've upgraded to XCode 4 and because IB is now inside none of my old NIB files will open getting a "An instance of ASKNibConnector could not be decoded" error. Is there a way to convert NIBs to XIBs without interface builder? or do you have to do something like reinstall 3, convert the nibs and reinstall 4?

Comment: that's odd.  I upgraded from xCode3 to xCode4 without any issues with my IB files.  I'd be curious how this one works out in the end.

Comment: all my stuff so far has been applescript based with IB for the GUI which may be the problem cause but no clear answer on how to fix it.

Answer (score 21):

To convert your nib to xib format, use the command line tool `ibtool` like this:

```
ibtool foo.nib --upgrade --write foo.xib
```

Or use this gist to find all your nibs and convert them: https://gist.github.com/254161